A seemingly stopped HTTP service continues to work
I wrote a python function, detailed in another post, which communicates with an HTTP-based RumbleDB server, running on my local machine, in order to evaluate JSONiq queries.
I tested the function in a Jupyter Notebook inside Visual Studio Code running on my Windows 10 laptop. Before executing the function, I started the RumbleDB server in a Git Bash console by executing the command
spark-submit rumbledb-1.21.0-for-spark-3.5.jar serve -p 9090

as instructed in the RumbleDB documentation.
After a few tests, I hit Ctrl+C inside the bash console in order to stop the server (as suggested in this post).
The server having been stopped (or so I thought), I restarted the Jupyter notebook where I did the testing, and reran it. To my surprise, the tests succeeded, and returned the expected values, with no error messages.
How can it be, if the RumbleDB process has stopped?
I tested which HTTP processes are listening to ports 9090 and 8001 (8001 is another port I used during the testing) by running the following commands in the Git Bash console:
netstat  -ano  |  findstr 9090
netstat  -ano  |  findstr 8001

The commands returned nothing, indicating, I presume, that no HTTP process is listening to these ports.
This only increased my puzzlement. Please help.
EDIT: I have restarted my computer, and immediately after it came back up, I opened Visual Studio Code and ran the tests. They succeeded! How can this be?

The problem was that the URL I used (http://public.rumbledb.org:9090/jsoniq) didn't point to the local host, but to a web-based host. Once I changed it to http://localhost:9090/jsoniq the problem was gone.
